# How to run function once at start of Quartz job in Grails, and persist variable values between calls?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I'm new to Groovy and Grails (and Java), I've got a Quartz scheduler job (code below), wondering

1.) How to do some init stuff (check the DB and initialise local variables) the first time the job is called (or at application startup, e.g. in another file, but then how do I set the counter variables in this job?

2.) Do the variables keep their values between calls to the job? If not, how do I do this?

```
class MyJob {
    static triggers = {
        simple repeatInterval: 1000l // execute job every 1 second
    }

    // These need to be initiated (with values from a DB) the first time the job is run:
    long myCounter1, myCounter2, myCounter3

    def execute() {

    if(first time job is run / application startup) {
    // get values for counters defined above, from DB
    }
    // else values should persist from last job run

    // Get stuff from database, passing in counter values

}
```

I'm using the Quartz plugin for Grails https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/introduction.html which uses the Quartz Scheduler http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/quick-start-guide.html

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried obvious - constructor. MyJob{ ...init here... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your job with `@PersistJobDataAfterExecution` and use [JobDataMap](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/index.html) to store/retrieve data between executions.

```
import org.quartz.*;

@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
public class ExampleJob {

    static triggers = {
        simple repeatInterval: 1000l // execute job every 1 second
    }

    @Override
    void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        JobDataMap jobDataMap = jobExecutionContext.jobDetails.jobDataMap
        Integer count = jobDataMap.get("count") ?: 0    
        jobDataMap.put("count", ++count)
    }
}
```

Comment: great thanks, so that uses the Quartz Scheduler directly rather than the Quartz plugin for Grails? And does it still go in my /grails-app/jobs folder?

Comment: You'll still need to have the Quartz plugin installed, and put the job classes in `grails-app/jobs`

Comment: thanks, so just to clarify (new to this!), your code replaces my whole class? Presume your count var gets replaced with my own myCounter1,2,3? And how do I get it to trigger once a second, do I just copy my triggers block from my code? Thanks

Comment: @AlexKerr I've updated my code with answers to your questions